# When I add a word to a dictionary in Microsoft Word, will it be marked as error if I share a document with another person?

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a document in which I want to add a new word to a dictionary. To can add a new word to a dictionary, I have to create custom dictionary first, because if not, the add word is disabled.

Well, my doubt is, if I share this document to another person, the word that I added to the dictionary to don't be marked as incorrect, will it be marked as incorrect when the other person will open the document?

If this is true, there is some way to embedded a dictionary to the document or mark this work as correct and it will not be marked as incorrect to other people that open this document?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it'll be marked as an error if the other system doesn't have it in the dictionary and no, it's not possible to embed your dictionary.

Comment: It is what I guessed, but I wanted to confirm. It is logic anyway. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Yes, a word in your custom dictionary will still show up as an error on the other computer. Instead, you can *mark* the word to not check spelling (on any computer).

Adding a word to your custom dictionary tells Word to approve that spelling on your computer when it runs a spell check. It has no effect when someone else opens it on a different computer, though.

Words and phrases in Word can be marked so that they are ***skipped** in spelling checks* and do not show up as errors in Word on any computer. This can be done by applying that setting to the text through the proofing language dialog or by using a character style with the setting. Such marking works on all computers opening the document in Word regardless of whether or not the word is in a user's dictionary of acceptable spellings. This is a form of invisible character formatting, not unlike Bold or Italics. See Word MVP Suzanne Barnhill's page on [Mastering the Spelling Checker](http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/MasterSpellCheck.htm#HidingErrors).

Here is [my article on creating a character style that you can use to mark words/phrases to not have spelling checked](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/creating-no-proofing-styles-in-microsoft-word-no/999c8de4-dac2-4fac-be07-ab55e8d636cc). Here are two of the macros from that article:

> ```
> Sub NoSpellCheckStyle()  ' SEE ALSO ASSIGNSHORTCUTNOSPELLCHECK FOLLOWING
>     ' Charles Kenyon
>     ' Creates a character style named "No Spell Check" in the Active Document
>     ' Does NOT apply the style to a selection, simply creates the style
>     ' 12 April 2019
>     '
>     Dim stlNoCheck As Style
>     '
>     On Error GoTo ErrorAlreadyExists
>     Set stlNoCheck = ActiveDocument.Styles.Add(Name:="No Spell Check", Type:=wdStyleTypeCharacter)
>     On Error GoTo -1
>     With stlNoCheck
>         .Font.Name = ""
>         .NoProofing = True
>     End With
>     GoTo ExitSub
> ErrorAlreadyExists:
>     MsgBox Prompt:="Style 'No Spell Check' already exists", Buttons:=vbInformation, title:="Oops"
> ExitSub:
>     Set stlNoCheck = Nothing
> End Sub
>
> Sub AssignShortcutNoSpellCheck()
> '
> ' Charles Kenyon ---- GOES WITH PREVIOUS MACRO
> ' 2 March 2021
> ' Assigns keyboard shortcut Ctrl+Shift+Alt+N to No Spell Check style
> '   Style must exist
> '   Saves this in the active document
> '
>     CustomizationContext = ActiveDocument ' Change ActiveDocument to NormalTemplate if style is in Normal Template
>     KeyBindings.Add KeyCode:=BuildKeyCode(wdKeyN, wdKeyControl, _
>         wdKeyShift, wdKeyAlt), _
>         KeyCategory:=wdKeyCategoryStyle, _
>         Command:="No Spell Check"
> End Sub
> ```

*My [article](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/creating-no-proofing-styles-in-microsoft-word-no/999c8de4-dac2-4fac-be07-ab55e8d636cc) also has a macro for a paragraph style and links to directions on how to use macros.*

Answer (score 2):

Each machine has a local `.dic` file, which is specific to that machine.

If I add `abcdefxyz` to a document, then add the word to my dictionary, send the document to someone else, they will see it underlined in red unless they add the word to their local dictionary.